# Mono C# app on Linux Debian multi language

Tags: c#, linux, unicode, fonts, mono

I have a multi language app that works no issues on windows. When I run it on Linux the Chinese characters display as squares.

The text is loaded from XML files that are encoded correctly - if I view them in a Linux text editor they display without issue. I've tried changing fonts (to that used in the text editor) without luck.

I hope to resolve this without having to change the environment LANG variable and re-booting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the WinForms app doesn't want to use the unicode characters with all built in fonts.

I added the following font:

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-wqy-microhei
```

Then ensured the textbox has it's font accordingly - e.g. for the above 'WenQuayYi Micro Hei'

No problems after this.